# Cpanel APN configuration

Tags: configuration, cpanel, apn

I want to enable APN in my cPanel server. As per the instructions, I should open the ports 2195 and 2196 for both inbound and outbound connections in the Config server firewall. Can someone tell how I do this on cpanel

Answer (score 0):

Have your added these port in firewall configuration? if yes, then may be these port are blocked in your DC (Server provider) end. Can you please ask your dc support team to confirm this and enable for your server.